# losing variable on other PC

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

first some explaints to my projekt:
i run an XAMPP server on machine A. On this machine is a browser opened which shows some "cards" in different states (to do, at progress and finished).
On an admin page i have the same cards in th states to do and finished.
If i click on an card, the visualisation turns into "at progress" and the admin page shows me the steps to do. if i click done, the visualisation of the card turns on the visualisation and the admin page into finished. if i clicked cancel, they turn to "to do".

My problem: if i run the admin page on machine A, all ok. if i run the admin page on an iPad-> all ok. But if i run the admin page from an other pc a $_POST variable gets lost.
The Admin page is a PHP file, which creates the javascript for each card.
i post the created source code within the browser.
here is the JavaScript/jQuery code for the functions:

```
function updateDatabase(cardnumber, ready, cardInEdit){
    var url2send = "./serverfunc.php";
    var text = cardnumber;
    var ready = ready;
    var edit = cardInEdit;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url2send,
            data: { action: 'updateState', card: text, status: ready, edit: edit},
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log("updateDatabase: update Karte "+text);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "ok") {
                    console.log("update Database erfolgreich ausgefuehrt");
                }
                if (data == "error") {
                    console.log("update Database bekam error");
                }
            }
        });
};
```

```
var card1 = document.getElementById("card1");
var cardFlipped1 = $("#card1").data("flip-model");
card1.addEventListener("click", function(){
if (cardFlipped1.isFlipped == false && 0 == 0){
   cardInEdit = true;
   status = false;
   getToDoList(1);
}else if (cardFlipped1.isFlipped == false && 0 == 1){
   cardInEdit = false;
   status = true;
}else{
   cardInEdit = false;
   status = false;
}
updateDatabase(1,status, cardInEdit);
});
```

```
function getToDoList(cardID) {
var url2send = "./serverfunc.php";
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url2send,
    data: { action: 'getToDoList', card: cardID },
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("getToDoList: sende Daten");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("getToDoList: Daten erhalten " + data);

        $("#popupcontent"+cardID).empty();

        //ist eine Karte in Bearbeitung, dann zeige das popup an
        $.each(data, function (i, field) {
        if(field.kind == 'text'){
            $("#popupcontent"+field.kartennummer).append("<li>"+field.wert+"</li>");
        }
        if(field.kind == 'image'){
            $("#popupcontent"+field.kartennummer).append("<li><img src=\"cardtodo/images/"+field.source+"\"></li>");
        }
        if(field.kind == 'movie'){
            $("#popupcontent"+field.kartennummer).append("<li><video width=\"320\" height=\"240\" controls><source src=\"cardtodo/movies/"+field.source+"\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video></li>");
        }
        if(field.kind == 'soundfile'){
            $("#popupcontent"+field.kartennummer).append("<li>Audio abspielen: <br/><audio controls=\"true\" src=\"cardtodo/audio/" + field.source + "\" type=\"audio/mp3\">Audio wird auf diesem Ger&auml;t nicht untertützt!</audio></li>");
        }

        });
    }
});
```

}

as mentioned above, if i watch the network traffic in ie, on machine A (where the server runs) it send on click "action=updateState&card=1&status=false&edit=true" and all fine. At an other machine it send "action=updateState&card=1&status=&edit=true". on an iPad all work fine (i dont know how to look at the send messages from ipad) why i lose the value of status just on an other machine?

Comment: what Browset is it on the other machine? tried another one?

Comment: and btw: you can get rid of `var ready = ready;`. That _could_ be an issue (instantiating a var -> deleting it's original content?)

Comment: no need to cooperate....it's your problem, not ours! I'm gone!

Comment: Browsers are allways ie11 except mobile Safari on iPad. I've tried Chrome at home, but only on local machine. The couriosity is that the Same code works on iPad and on the local machine.

Comment: and thanks for the `var ready = ready;` mistake. i changed it. but the failure is, that the variable status is send "empty" to the function and not "cleared" inside the function.